# How can fbi iteratively display images as they are created without keyboard input

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi3, debian-stretch

I am capturing images from the pi camera to a raspberry pi 3 running raspbian stretch lite. Each image is processed with some python code. I want to display each processed image until the next one is captured. Each image has the label 'image' followed by a sequence number. I am trying to use fbi to display each image. When fbi displays an image, it seems it blocks and then waits for keyboard input before going on to the next image. I realize there is the option of using the switch , -t seconds, but that only works if you give fbi a list of images to process. For example

```
import os
#get an image and do stuff to it
os.system("sudo fbi -t 3 image1.jpg")
#get next image and do stuff to it
os.system("sudo fbi -t 3 image2.jpg")
```

Unless I hit the spacebar when it's showing the first image, I never get to see the next image. If I use this instead

```
import os
#get an image and do stuff to it
os.system("sudo fbi -t -1 image1.jpg")
sleep(3)
#get next image and do stuff to it
os.system("sudo fbi -t -1 image2.jpg")
sleep(3)
```

the images flash by too quickly.

Is there any way to get fbi to iteratively display images without keyboard input?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding correctly, so forgive me - what is the requirement that doens't allow you to pass `fbi` a list of images? `sudo fbi -t 3 image1.jpg image2.jpg`

Comment: the images do not exist at the time of the fbi call. the images are generated from camera captures, so i have to call fbi after processing each image. but when fbi is called, i do not know how to kill it after a predetermined time. it's waiting for keyboard action. i'd rather not have to programmatically emulate a key press if there is a better way.